# Kotlin "variable expected" error when doing assignment to Array element

Tags: kotlin, nested-function

I'm writing the following nested function where dfsVisit uses the arrays "numCaminos" and "colores" declared in the outer function
[image]

However the kotlin compiler is giving me a "variable expected" error on the assignments in lines 31 and 34 specifically, this error doesn't show up on any of the other Array assignments within the nested dfsVisit function. I tried de-nesting the functions and passing the arrays as arguments of dfsVisit but the problem persisted on those 2 assignments specifically. Why could this be happening?

I'm running the Kotlin compiler in Manjaro Linux through the repository package

Note: Sorry for using a picture instead of a code block, the post editor was giving me some formatting issues.

Comment: For reference, [this answer](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/10134209) explains some reasons why posting text is better than images; it also links to [this question](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251361/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks) giving info on how to format code blocks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just remove `!!` from the left side of the assignment. It doesn't really make sense there.

Comment: Well this was anti-climactic, thanks it worked